# How to validate a twitter bootstrap form wizard

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap, formwizard

I am using twitter bootstrap and want to combine form wizard with validation. But after trying very much the form wizard and validation is not working on next botton. Where I am making mistake. My coding is below

```
<div class="portlet-body form">
                        <form action="#" id="form_sample_2" class="form-horizontal">
                           <div class="form-wizard">
                              <div class="navbar steps">
                                 <div class="navbar-inner">
                                    <ul class="row-fluid nav nav-pills">
                                       <li class="span3 active">
                                          <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="step active">
                                          <span class="number">1</span>
                                          <span class="desc"> Registration</span>   
                                          </a>
                                       </li>
                                       <li class="span3">
                                          <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="step">
                                          <span class="number">2</span>
                                          <span class="desc"> Review Application</span>   
                                          </a>
                                       </li>
                                     </ul>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                              <div id="bar" class="progress progress-success progress-striped">
                                 <div class="bar" style="width: 25%;"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="tab-content background-color-blue">
                                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
                                    <h3 class="block">Registration</h3>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">UserName:</label>
                                       <div class="controls span8">
                                          <input type="text" data-required="1" name="username" id="username" value="user" class="span6 m-wrap">
                                          <span class="help-inline">UsernameTip</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">PassWord:</label>
                                       <div class="controls span8">
                                          <input type="password" data-required="1" name="password" id="password" value="password" class="span6 m-wrap">
                                          <span class="help-inline">{L_PassWordTip}</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">ConfirmPassWord:</label>
                                       <div class="controls span8">
                                          <input type="password" data-required="1" name="password2" id="password2" value="password2" class="span6 m-wrap">
                                          <span class="help-inline">ConfirmPassWordTip</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>                                
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                                    <h3 class="block">AppReview</h3>
                                     <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Entered UserName:</label>
                                       <div class="controls span8">
                                          <span class="text" id="username_pr"></span>
                                       </div>
                                     </div>
                                    <div class="control-group">
                                       <label class="control-label">Entered PassWord:</label>
                                       <div class="controls span8">
                                          <span class="text">**Hidden**</span>
                                       </div>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="clearfix">
                                 <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-large btn-info button-previous" style="display: none;">
                                 <i class="m-icon-swapleft m-icon-white"></i> Back 
                                 </a>
                                 <a href="javascript:;" onclick="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-info button-next">
                                 Continue <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
                                 </a>
                                 <a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-large btn-success button-submit" style="display: none;">
                                 Submit <i class="m-icon-swapright m-icon-white"></i>
                                 </a>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                        </form>
                     </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var FormWizard = function () {


    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            if (!jQuery().bootstrapWizard) {
                return;
            }

            // default form wizard
            $('#form_sample_2').bootstrapWizard({
                'nextSelector': '.button-next',
                'previousSelector': '.button-previous',
                onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    alert('on tab click disabled');
                    return false;
                },

                onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;
                    // set wizard title
                    $('.step-title', $('#form_sample_2')).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
                    // set done steps
                    jQuery('li', $('#form_sample_2')).removeClass("done");
                    var li_list = navigation.find('li');
                    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                        jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
                    }

                    if (current == 1) {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-previous').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-previous').show();
                    }

                    if (current >= total) {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-next').hide();
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-submit').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-next').show();
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-submit').hide();
                    }
                    App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
                },
                onPrevious: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;
                    // set wizard title
                    $('.step-title', $('#form_sample_2')).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
                    // set done steps
                    jQuery('li', $('#form_sample_2')).removeClass("done");
                    var li_list = navigation.find('li');
                    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                        jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
                    }

                    if (current == 1) {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-previous').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-previous').show();
                    }

                    if (current >= total) {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-next').hide();
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-submit').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-next').show();
                        $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-submit').hide();
                    }

                    App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
                },
                onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = (current / total) * 100;
                    $('#form_sample_2').find('.bar').css({
                        width: $percent + '%'
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#form_sample_2').find('.button-previous').hide();
            $('#form_sample_2 .button-submit').click(function () {
                alert('Finished! Hope you like it :)');
            }).hide();
        }

    };

}();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var FormValidation = function () {


    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {

            //Sample 2
            var form2 = $('#form_sample_2');
            var error2 = $('.alert-error', form2);
            var success2 = $('.alert-success', form2);
            form2.validate({
                errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
                errorClass: 'help-inline', // default input error message class
                focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
                ignore: "",
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        minlength: 5,
                        maxlength: 32,
                        required: true
                    },
                    password:{
                        minlength: 4,
                        maxlength: 32,
                        required:true
                    },
                    password2:{
                        required:true,
                        equalTo:password
                    },
                },


                errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                        error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavoir
                },

                invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                    success2.hide();
                    error2.show();
                    App.scrollTo(error2, -200);
                },

                highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.help-inline').removeClass('ok'); // display OK icon
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group

                },

                unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change dony by hightlight
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
                },

                success: function (label) {
                        label
                        .addClass('valid').addClass('help-inline ok') // mark the current input as valid and display OK icon
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success'); // set success class to the control group
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    success2.show();
                    error2.hide();
                }

            });

        }

    };

}();
</script>


<script src="js/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/plugins/wizard-master/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My goal: stop the wizard from transferring to the next tab if any field in current step is not valid. Allow the user to fix all invalid fields and only then move on to the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning an id to

```
<div class="form-wizard" id="form2_steps">
```

And replace $('#form_sample_2').bootstrapWizard with $('#form2_steps').bootstrapWizard
and other with this "form2_steps"
After: onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
add this coding:

```
var $valid = $("#form_sample_2").valid();
                if(!$valid) {
                    form2.focusInvalid();
                    return false;
                }
```

Complete solution in a combined script is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">         
var FormValidation = function () {

    return {        
        init: function () {
                //Sample 2
                var form2 = $('#form_sample_2');
                var error2 = $('.alert-error', form2);
                var success2 = $('.alert-success', form2);

                form2.validate({
                errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
                focusInvalid: true, // do not focus the last invalid input
                ignore: ':hidden',
                rules: {
                    username: {
                        minlength: 5,
                        maxlength: 32,
                        required: true
                    },
                    password:{
                        minlength: 4,
                        maxlength: 32,
                        required:true
                    },
                    password2:{
                        required:true,
                        equalTo:password
                    },
                },


                errorPlacement: function (error, element) { // render error placement for each input type
                        error.insertAfter(element); // for other inputs, just perform default behavoir
                },

                invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { //display error alert on form submit   
                    success2.hide();
                    error2.show();
                    App.scrollTo(error2[0], -200);
                },

                highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.help-inline').removeClass('ok'); // display OK icon
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group

                },

                unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change dony by hightlight
                    $(element)
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
                },

                success: function (label) {
                        label
                        .addClass('valid').addClass('help-inline ok') // mark the current input as valid and display OK icon
                        .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success'); // set success class to the control group
                },

                submitHandler: function (form) {
                    success2.show();
                    error2.hide();
                }

            });

        }

    };

}();

var FormWizard = function () {


    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function () {
            if (!jQuery().bootstrapWizard) {
                return;
            }

            // default form wizard
            $('#form2_steps').bootstrapWizard({
                'nextSelector': '.button-next',
                'previousSelector': '.button-previous',
                onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    alert('on tab click disabled');
                    return false;
                },

                onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var $valid = $("#form_sample_2").valid();
                    if(!$valid) {
                        form2.focusInvalid();
                        return false;
                    }                    
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;

                    // set wizard title
                    $('.step-title', $('#form2_steps')).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
                    // set done steps
                    jQuery('li', $('#form2_steps')).removeClass("done");
                    var li_list = navigation.find('li');
                    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                        jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
                    }
                    // Make sure we entered the name

                    if (current == 1) {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-previous').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-previous').show();
                    }

                    if (current >= total) {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-next').hide();
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-submit').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-next').show();
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-submit').hide();
                    }
                    App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
                },
                onPrevious: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;
                    // set wizard title
                    $('.step-title', $('#form2_steps')).text('Step ' + (index + 1) + ' of ' + total);
                    // set done steps
                    jQuery('li', $('#form2_steps')).removeClass("done");
                    var li_list = navigation.find('li');
                    for (var i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                        jQuery(li_list[i]).addClass("done");
                    }

                    if (current == 1) {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-previous').hide();
                    } else {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-previous').show();
                    }

                    if (current >= total) {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-next').hide();
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-submit').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-next').show();
                        $('#form2_steps').find('.button-submit').hide();
                    }

                    App.scrollTo($('.page-title'));
                },
                onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
                    var total = navigation.find('li').length;
                    var current = index + 1;
                    var $percent = (current / total) * 100;
                    $('#form2_steps').find('.bar').css({
                        width: $percent + '%'
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#form2_steps').find('.button-previous').hide();
            $('#form2_steps .button-submit').click(function () {
                alert('Finished! Hope you like it :)');
            }).hide();
        }
    };

}();
</script>
```